# how can i use curl to login into non digest login sites?

Tags: networking, windows-10, command-line, router, curl

the router login page

[image]

i have tried

> curl  http://admin:admin@**.**.**.***/

but it doesn't work

Comment: i found it but still doesn't work !
https://ghostbin.com/paste/a2p4v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the network tap using ctrl+shift+I

[image]
then reload the page

[image]

type the password and the username then click submit/login

in the network tap you will find router ip 
[image]

right click on it and click  copy the command  as curl (cmd) 
[image]

then remove all the ^ from the command then past it in cmd and you are done

so the command just looks like this

```
curl "http://192.168.1.1/" --data "frashnum=&action=login&Frm_Logintoken=24&Username=admin&Password=ZAQXSWCDEVFR"  -v
```

and don't forget to update the Frm_Logintoken

> the Frm_Logintoken is a token generated by the router and it basically
>   increment by one on each successful login!

you will find it in the router page html code in the elements tap or view page source code ctrl + U
then ctrl + F and type token then press enter 
and look for the value !